# Real equivalent of the surreal number {0.5|}

Tags: real-numbers, surreal-numbers

I've been reading up on Surreal numbers, but have some questions.

Some equivalent real and surreal numbers.

```
2.5 =
    {2|3} =
    {{{0|}|}|{{{0|}|}|}} =
    {{{{{|}}|{}}|{}}|{{{{{|}}|{}}|{}}|{}}}

0 =
    {-1|1} = {-2|1} = {-2,-1|1} =
    {{|0}|{0|}} = {{|{|0}},{|0}|{0|}} =
    {{{}|{{|}}}|{{{|}}|{}}}

-3/8 = {-0.5|-0.25} = {{-1|0}|{{-1|0}|0}}
    {{{{}|{{|}}}|{{{}|{{|}}}|{{|}}}}|{{{}|{{|}}}|{{|}}}}
```

What about the real number for {0.5|}?

Comment: Read $\{\frac{1}{2}\;|\;\}$ as: "the simplest number larger than $1/2$".

Comment: Thanks, an elegant way to think about it.

Comment: Note that surreal _numbers_ are equivalence classes of _forms_ (where forms contain numbers). So things like `0` and `2.5` are names for surreal numbers that happen to coincide with the names given to real numbers in decimal notation, and what you have in each equation are different representations of the same number. Not that it really changes the validity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the surreal numbers, $$\{0.5|\}=1=\{0|\}=\{\{|\}|\}.$$

In general, if $a$ is real and $a\ge 0$, $$\{a\mid\}=\{\lfloor a\rfloor\mid\}=\lfloor a \rfloor+1,$$ where $\lfloor a \rfloor$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $a$.  If $a<0$, $$\{a\mid\}=\{\mid\}=0.$$

Comment: The case $\{a|\} = 0$ if $a < 0$ is true because whoever starts the game loses (definition of zero)

Answer (score 1):

The number for {1/2|} is "1"...

```
a = {{{|}|{{|}|}}|}
numeric label for a = 1
a == "1" = True
Surreal {1/2|} represented by form {{{|}|{{|}|}}|}
 is equivalent to form {{|}|} represented by name "1"
```

...according to python code...

```
from surreal import creation, Surreal
s = creation(days=7)
a = Surreal([s[1/2]],[])
name = a.name_in(s)
equivelence = s[name]
print('a =',a)
print('numeric label for a =',name)
print('a == "{}" = {}'.format(name,a==equivelence))
print('Surreal {} represented by form {}'.format('{1/2|}',str(a)))
print(' is equivalent to form {} represented by name "{}"'.format(str(equivelence),name))
```

...using [PySurreal] (https://github.com/peawormsworth/PySurreal):

Answer (score 0):

Consider the games, which happen to be numbers, $G = \{ 0\,|\,\}$ and $H = \{ 0.5\,|\,\}$.

$G = 1$, directly from the simplicity rules. You know that $H = 1$, but that is not a direct implication. What you can do is show that $G \leq H \leq G$.

$H \leq G$, because $0.5$ is the only Left option of $H$, there are no Right options in $G$ and $0.5 < G = 1$.

$G \leq H$, because $0$ is the only Left option of $G$, there are no Right options in $H$ and $0 < H$. The last inequality, $0 < H$, is true because in the game $H$, Left wins no matter who starts, and this means the game is positive.

Now it is clear that $\{ 0\,|\,\} = \{ 0.5\,|\,\} =  1$. I hope that it helps you understanding why Polichinelle's answer is correct.